# Не сохраняет в базу данных .mdf

Tags: c#

Помогите побороть проблему. Не сохраняет данные введенные в dataGridView.

Имеется dataGridView в нем заполняются данные (имеются также другие таблицы которые привязаны по Primary Key) при сохранении вылетает ошибка. База данных SQL Server'a

P.S. Как уж не менял - не сохраняет или уже другие ошибки в коде появляются. Если кто поможет буду благодарен.

и есть ещё предупреждение:

```
Warning 1 Field 'abc.Form1.ds' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
```

Код:

```
namespace azeeska
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        DataSet ds;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder;
        string ConnStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\123\base.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        //Выбор всего из
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Азс";

 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


 private void button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
            {
                connection.Open();
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
                commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_CreateUser", connection);
                adapter.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ппп", SqlDbType.Text, 50, "тип ппп"));
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ффф", SqlDbType.Text, 0, "тип ффф"));
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ззз", SqlDbType.Text, 50, "тип ззз"));
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ммм", SqlDbType.Text, 0, "тип ммм"));
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип ккк", SqlDbType.Text, 50, "тип ккк"));
                adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@тип щщщ", SqlDbType.Text, 0, "тип щщщ"));

                SqlParameter parameter = adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@№ азс", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "№ азс");
                parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                adapter.Update(ds);

    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]